# Start JRubyStack with Console 2

Tags: jruby, console2

I have installed the JRuby Stack environment in Windows which uses the default windows cmd as a console. I want to use Console 2 but unfourtunately I don't know how to configure it.

I tried creating a new tab in Console to and in Shell I gave it the path to

```
"C:\Program Files\BitNami JRubyStack\use_jruby.bat"
```

Unfourtunately, this bat opens the CMD by default:

@echo off

```
CALL C:\PROGRA~1\BITNAM~1\scripts\setenv.bat"
cd "C:\Program Files\BitNami JRubyStack"
START "BitNami JRubyStack Environment" cmd
```

So.. any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: That line that says `START "BitNami JRubyStack Environment" cmd` is the culprit, I think. Change `cmd` to the path to the Console 2 executable.

Comment: No.. that didn't work, I've tried it before posting..

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what the Stack provides and how much you need it, but I don't see any reason the regular JRuby install would be incompatible with Console 2.